# How store for loop results to data frame?

Tags: r

I have a list of files that I need to perform analysis. I would like to store the results of each iteration to a data frame as a new row. Here is what I tried but got the error:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "c1", value = c(0, 64010, 0, 64010, : replacement has 2 rows, data has 65
```

Here is my code (this part of the code only counts number of records in each file)

```
h <- data.frame(matrix(0, ncol = 2, nrow = 65))
colnames(y) <- c("c1","c2")

my_files <- list.files("C:/Users/....")
for (i in 1:length(my_files))
{
k <- length(readLines(my_files[i], skipNul=TRUE))
 h$c1 <- rbind(h$c1, k)
}
```

Comment: `k <- readLines(my_files[i], skipNul=TRUE)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`length` will give you a single number. You are trying to `rbind` a single value into a two column object. One solution would be to add an NA in column c2 in your loop like so:

```
h <- rbind(h, c(k,NA))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to stay away from for loops. Consider using one of the [apply](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/lapply.html) functions, like lapply.